# apt-get install packages introduces lots of python errors on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt

`apt-get install -y my_package`
Everything works until
`Setting up my_package...`
And lots of python errors like the below appeared:

```
Compiling ./ext/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py ...
  File "./ext/python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 77
    raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect it has something to do with python versions

```
ls -la /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

Comment: can you run `which python3`?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki the result is `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: ok, so it looks like you have python3 installed. Does `apt update` work fine or does it throw errors? Also, does this error happen with any package or just this one?

Comment: What is `my_package`? It sounds like it's been packaged badly (and is running Python 2's `compileall` against Python 3 files).

Comment: @AKX you're right, turns out there's a mistake in a script for python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the symptoms, sounds like a packaging bug.

It looks like the package's scripts are expecting `python` to be Python 3 and is thus inadvertently running Python 2's compileall against Python 3 files.